# Local uncommited changes in master. Need to switch to another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am WebDev intern and I have done some work in the master branch. 
And I have done a week's work without realising that I am in the master branch. 
I need to switch branches so that I can commit my local changes from a branch that is not the master branch. 
What I need to do:

- Take all the local changes from my master branch to some other branch.
- Commit changes from that branch.
- Give you a correct answer verification. :P

I went through some answers but I don't think that they are catering to my exact situation.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Just create a new branch based on the latest commit on master. Your changes will travel with you as long as they are on the same commit. If they are not on the same commit, an error message will be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do would be to stash your working directory (and possibly stage, if you have staged any files), create a new feature branch, and then apply your stash there.

```
# from the master branch
git stash                      # stash your work
git checkout -b your_feature   # create and switch to a feature branch
git stash apply                # then apply your work to that branch
```

Then, you may commit your work to the `your_feature` branch:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Finished my work'
```

The `git stash` command works by making two (or sometimes three) commits containing the contents of your working directory and stage.  It then would rollback `master` to the point where you first began.

Answer (score 0):

If you already apply some commit to the master in locally. The solution that I will do in this case is:

1) At first creat a new brach which will be a copy of master.

```
git checkout -b new_branch master
```

2) Now push the new_branch in remote (if you want)

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

3) Now go to the master

```
git checkout master
```

4) Now go to the log, and see number of commit you have done that you want to delete from master.

```
git log
```

Lets 'N' be the number of commit you have done. So, to delete these commit from master use this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

For example, you want to delete recent 5 commit. So, it will be:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

Hope it will help you.